# Ruggedized enclosure for 3.5" hard drives

Tags: hard-disk, drive-enclosure

I'm looking for a *ruggedized* enclosure for *3.5"* hard drives. These exist for 2.5" drives (like [this one](http://www.raidsonic.de/de/standards/searchresults.php?we_objectID=3580)), but I haven't seen one for 3.5" drives.

My requirements:

- Disk enclosure for one 3.5" form-factor SATA disk
- Compatible with *large* discs, i.e. 8TB++ (electronically and mechanically)
- Good passive cooling
- USB 3.x data interface
- Externally powered with a switch to turn it off
- Available in Germany

Wanted, but not required:

- eSATA data interface

My use case is intermittent backup where the disks and enclosure are only on and spinning during the backups and then transported off-site for use in disaster recovery.